# Autocomplete Positiong in FireFox (using Bootstrap)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, autocomplete

I am very new to the bootstrap framework and I am working on an input form that should populate an autocomplete list based on past browsing history. I have tested everything on IE and Chrome and the autocomplete box lines up directly underneath the input box like it should, however, in FF 31 (on Windows 7 platform - 2 monitors) the autocomplete box shows up on my second monitor display.

I was told it can be a 2 monitor issue.

Someone also told me it's FF browser issue. Another said it's a Bootstrap thing.

I've done some research and have found others suggesting the Z-index as well as postion: absolute

If anyone has encountered a similar problem I would appreciate any guidance you can provide.

Thanks for your time - Rich

Comment: Can you provide the block of code you're using for your input form? We can validate it's correct.

Comment: Hi Tyler, This is the style I have assigned .ui-autocomplete {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 cursor: default;
}

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a very similar problem. I fixed it by modifying the way it is positioned on the page.

The "translate" css properties was having issues in firefox.

It seems to place the autocomplete box where  the element was originally drawn and not where it ends up after css is applied. Like I said my issue is very similar and it could lead to a solution of yours.

Translate Breaks it:

```
div{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    transform: translate(30%);
    width:100%;
}
```

Removing Translate and changing how it positions fixes it:

```
div{
    text-align:center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 25px;
    left:30%;
}
```

[Here's a jsfiddle example of what I ran into and fixed](http://jsfiddle.net/cpd6jch7/4/)